# Converting a Union<'a> to a Union<'b>

Tags: generics, f#, discriminated-union

Say I have an F# discriminated union defined like so:

```
type Union<'T> = | A of 'T | B | C
```

If I have a `B` of this where `'T` is `int` for example, how would I convert it to another `B` where `'T` is a `string`? I have a union similar to this but with many more cases, and currently I pattern match like this:

```
let convert u =
  match u with
  | A(x) -> // some fancy logic here
  | B -> B
  | C -> C
```

Answer (score 8):

This function is usually called `map`. The first argument is a function `(a -> b)` to transform the inner value:

```
let map f = function
  | A(x) -> (A (f x))
  | B -> B
  | C -> C
```

You can use it like:

```
let stringUnion = (A(123)) |> map (fun i -> i.ToString())
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly what I'm doing currently, and I was wondering if there's a way to get out of the repitition of writing `| Blah -> Blah` every time I create a new case; I change this particular union often.